# Why does my tankless water heater turn off when I open the cold side of the faucet?

Tags: water-heater, tankless

Just got a new Canon tankless water heater. I was wondering, why does the heater go out when I turn on a cold water knob while the hot water knob is still open. Like, I'll turn on the left/hot water knob and hot water starts flowing in a few seconds. I leave the left knob as is, and turn on the right/cold water knob. The heater turns off, and obviously, cold water is now coming out of the tap. Why doesnt the heater stay on? In case I want a continous flow of less-hot water without having to adjust the heater switches.

Comment: Welcome. What makes you think it's "going out"? Is it a gas unit that you can hear? More information on the plumbing configuration would be great. If you're not already familiar with SE sites, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I mean the heater completely turns off. Stops heating. Yes I also hear the system ceasing operation. It's a Canon CA - 16D Plus.

Comment: I presume you can't upload photos from android. I'll upload a photo of the manual in a bit from my computer.

Comment: Sure you can. You just need adequate reputation. That's not what I asked for, though. We need to see or know how the unit is connected, whether there's any other hardware involved, etc.

Comment: post a link to the manual instead

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to which information. This is not my forte at all.

Comment: You need enough pressure and flow or differential across the heater or it will shutdown as a safety. To reduce this problem in a house the owner only wanted 40 psi max I had to install pressure regulators and increased the tank pressure, this worked for that job and kept his internal plumbing at 40 psi.

Comment: @EdBeal oh so the cold water slows the hot water from the heater enough so the heater thinks water is not flowing? The rate of flow of the cold water is somewhat greater than the water from the heater. Need to get plumbing checked, incase something is restricting flow to/from heater?

Comment: The heater has some restrictions and if the pressure differential is two low it shuts down it is a safety thing. this keeps the unit from turning on with loss of pressure , the MFG suggested pressure regulation so the cold did not back flow causing the shutdown. It has been many years I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: @EdBeal yeah i think i get it. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I think you're onto it.  It's either a ratty old mixing valve that has 2 plain faucets blending in the spigot, or it's you slamming the cold water valve wide open instead of easing it open.